# CSS putting menu inline with the content

Tags: css

so i have this menu that doesn't want to get inline with the content no matter what i do.
here are some pictures, how it is now (before) and how i want it to be (after).

http://s24.postimg.org/nqv765rhx/image.jpg
http://s27.postimg.org/7jikbzrqr/image.jpg

here is the code:

```
#the website format{
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100%;
    text-align:left;
}
#menu {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
}
#wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    float:left;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.inside {
    width: 220px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DncKd/), is this the kind of look you're after?

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>Menu</div>
    <div class='cell'>Content</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    position:fixed;
}
.table{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.cell{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
.cell:first-child{
    width:100px;
}
```